# "Tell, don't ask" when one class is doing and storing calculations with data from another

Tags: oop, tell-dont-ask

Please tell me if I'm applying the *Tell, dont't ask* principle in right way in this example.

I have two classes, `CalculationResults` has a function `calculateMe()`, which uses `Data` to make some calculations. It is important that it stores the results.

```
class Data {
private:
  int dataForCalculations;
public:
  void calculate(CalculationResults& calculationResults) {
    calculationResults.calculateMe(dataForCalculations);
  }
};

class CalculationResults {
private:
  int calculatedData;
public:
  void calculateMe(int dataForCalculations) {
    calculatedData = someCalculations(dataForCalculations);
  }
};

// somewhere else:
Data data;
CalculationResults calculationResults;
data.calculate(calculationResults);
```

First version of this code (before applying *Tell, don't ask*) didn't use `Data::calculate` function but it has a `getter` for `dataForCalculations`, so somewhere I called `calculationResults.calculateMe(data.getDataForCalculations())`.

Is the new version better?

Comment: In any case I'll never use "output parameters". If you are going to transform a parameter return the transformed parameter.

Comment: @Ezequiel - You mean: `CalculationResults Data::calculate() { CalculationResults cr; cr.calculateMe(dataForCalculations); return cr; }`, yes?

Answer (score 5):

> Is the new version better?

That depends on who you ask.  But to be sure, the new version is 100% tell, don't ask.  It's easy to tell, because your methods return void.

Personally, I have had my run with trying to purely follow the tell, don't ask principle, and have given up on it for a couple reasons.

For one, the tell, don't ask principle can lead to conceptually confusing object interactions.  Take your code for example.  I wouldn't expect a `Data` object to be able to calculate itself. I would expect `Data` to be the input of something else.

As another example.  If I were writing a program that modeled making a call to someone, I might have a `Phone`, and `PhoneNumber`, and a `Person` object.  Now, according to tell, don't ask, you are supposed to ask the object with the data to accomplish a certain action.  So, in this case `PhoneNumber` might have a dial() method on it: `phoneNumber.dial()`.  But does that make sense, conceptually?  Really, a `Person` dials a `PhoneNumber` into a `Phone`.

So, that's my first problem.  I find it harder to understand, and I find it more difficult to come up with natural interactions between object with tell, don't ask, which slows me down.

Secondly, often times it's not clear which object should be called first when two objects need to share data.  Take a `Book` and a `Pen` for example.  Do you say `book.writeWith(pen)` or `pen.writeOn(book)`?  Maybe an argument can be made with that example, but often times you'll find the difference is arbitrary, and I hate that.

Thirdly, with tell, don't ask, an object will slowly build up more and more responsibilities.  Do you tell the object to save itself?  Do you tell it to display itself?  What if you have more than one view technology?  What if you need to display your object in different formats?  Do you ask your object to email itself?  Having an object with many responsibilities isn't necessarily bad.  It's less flexible to change, but provides an easier to work with API.  However, most people prefer flexibility, and having an object with few responsibilities is part of SOLID code.

Fourthly, what really is the difference between having your object pass it's private's around to other objects by using tell, don't ask (when you need to share data), and having a getter?  Not much, if you ask me.

I know this is very oppinion based, but I prefer your first version better because it it simpler, and clearer. However, I would write it instead as:

```
calculationResults.calculate(data);
```

Anyways, just my 2 cents.

Comment: so how you would solve that problem book.writeWith(pen) VS pen.writeOn(book), a third class named controller/service, which do that logic asking the involved classes pen and book for their internal state to be sure doing the wrting with the pen into the book? That would i call classic procedurla-programming an its one more argument for that oop doesnt work. Maybe there is one more class involved, a user for example. book.writeWithPenAndUser(pen, user) ^^